# Django do not ask user from database for request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

In my Django project I have a public API endpoint built with Django Rest Framework's `APIView`. It does not need to know anything about the user. Still, Django automatically fetches the session and the user from the database. Is there a way to not do this since it causes two unnecessary DB hits?

Here is the code:

```py
class TermListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        qs = Term.objects.all().only('original_word')
        return Response([term.original_word for term in qs])
```

Comment: How are you determining you're hitting the DB for the session and user? That same debugging tool should be able to show you the stack to that DB query, and you can then eliminate what's causing it.

Comment: I am using Django Debug Toolbar. Thank you for your quick replay; I found the solution and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `authentication_classes = ()` to the View class. This tells Django not to worry about the user. Or you can also configure this option globally for all your endpoints.

Comment: ... your original post already had `authentication_classes = ()` before you edited it out?